# Update database entry in Room using WorkManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I am trying to use `WorkManager` in Android because till now I have done my insert updates using `AsyncTask`. 
I'm trying to update user in `Room database`. I have created a class in `Repository` to do the process in background but I don't know if this is the right way to code. Also I am a bit confused how to call the method in userViewModel.

Here is my code:

In Repository:

```
inner class Test(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(ctx, params) {

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        fun updateUser(userId : Int , userName :String , userLastname: String){
            userDao.updateUser(userId, userName, userLastname)
        }
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

And in viewModel:

```
private val workManager: WorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance()
fun updateUser(userID: Int, userName: String, userLastname: String)    {
    workManager.enqueue(OneTimeWorkRequest.from(Repository.Test::class.java))

}
```

Maybe this is not the right way to use WorkManager so I would appreciate it if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Updated to support `Coroutine Worker`

You can use your code with minor changes. You can pass your parameters like userId, userName etc to `WorkManager` using `Data` class. Also there is no need to make the `Worker` class an inner class. Just make it an independent class.So basically, you `worker` class would look something like:

**TestWorker.kt**

```
class TestWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(ctx, params) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val userId = inputData.getInt("USER_ID")
        val userName = inputData.getString("USER_NAME")
        val userLastname = inputData.getString("USER_LAST_NAME") 
        AppDatabase.getInstance().userDao.updateUser(userId, userName, userLastname)
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

**TestViewModel.kt**

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel() {
    fun updateUser(userId: Int, userName: String, userLastName: String) {
        val worker = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(TestWorker::class.java)
        val data = Data.Builder()
        //Add parameter in Data class. just like bundle. You can also add Boolean and Number in parameter.
        data.putInt("USER_ID", userId)
        data.putString("USER_NAME", userName)
        data.putString("USER_LAST_NAME", userLastName)
        //Set Input Data
        worker.setInputData(data.build())
        //enque worker
        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(worker.build())
    }
}
```

> **Don't forget to make your database singleton like this:**

```
@Database(entities = [User::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao

    companion object {

        // For Singleton instantiation
        @Volatile
        private var instance: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }

        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context) =
            Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, "userdb")
                .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Ankur, is it required to use `WorkManager` with `Room`? If I don't then won't be there any guarentee of proper update to the database?

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB not it's not necessary. The person who asked the question was doing it through `WorkManager`, hence i provided the solution in context of work manager. I think he was using it for deferring the task to background thread. Ideally you should be using `Coroutines` or `RxJava` or any other async framework.

Comment: Won't the coroutines will be halted if the process stops?

Comment: If you're using Kotlin, you probably want to use `CoroutineWorker` per https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker.

Comment: @Bink Yes definitely. But the answer was given in Jan'19 when `workmanger` had no support for coroutines. I will update the answer anyways.

Comment: @ankuranurag2, fair.  There’s just a lot of outdated information on stack overflow, so I try to do my part to keep things more current—I just didn’t feel comfortable readily making changes to your rather complete answer.

Comment: This is not working because you have to make `doWork` function is `suspend`. And the context is not passed.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you got error `make doWork suspend`,  you can snippet following answer below.

```
class TestWorker(ctx: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(ctx, params) {
    val context = ctx
    
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val userId = inputData.getInt("USER_ID")
        val userName = inputData.getString("USER_NAME")
        val userLastname = inputData.getString("USER_LAST_NAME") 
        AppDatabase.getInstance(context).userDao.updateUser(userId, userName, userLastname)
        return Result.success()
    }
}
```

detail changes:

<s>Worker</s> CoroutineWorker

override **suspend** fun doWork(): Result